# Can't connect to memcached with PHP on OSX

Tags: php, macos, caching, memcached

I have installed memcache and the php extension also, it shows up correctly in the phpinfo().

However, when I try to test it with PHP, it fails to connect.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

The second line fails, but it doesn't even return "Could not connect", but the browser just returns a No data recieved error. No matter if I set error reporting in, it doesn't give me anything.

What could be the problem?

edit:

`netstat -na | grep 11211` shows:

```
tcp6       0      0  *.11211                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.11211                *.*                    LISTEN     
udp6       0      0  *.11211                *.*                               
udp4       0      0  *.11211                *.*
```

Comment: Important point: do you have `memcache`, `memcached`, or both? They differ (and the confustion this usually created has been A Bad Thing IMHO).

Comment: well, in the command line if i type memcache, its not found, if i type memcached it says its running. in the phpinfo it reads Memcache.

Comment: So, the [`memcache`](http://php.net/memcache) rather then the [`memcached`](http://php.net/memcached) extension. Should work, what does `class_exists("memcache");` yield? And does `netstat -na | grep 11211` show a listening process?  And keep in mind to catch most fatal & parse errors, display_errors & error_reporting should be set in the _configuration_, NOT in a php-file.

Comment: the functions returns true. i've updated my answer with the result of netstat. thanks for the config tip, i updated my php.ini, still no helpful errors though.

Comment: So it returns true, and then.... you output some data? Or what? If that portion works, but it's the only portion, of course there is no output to the client.

Comment: i try a sample memcached example, which works fine on my ubuntu machine, but not on my osx one. no output, no error message, just my browser returns 'No data received' error.

Comment: No data sent is no data received..... And it may be your different browser that doesn't like an empty page rather then anything else. If you just `var_dump($memcache);` after this, do you have output?

Comment: same result. im also trying a simple memcached example, including setting and getting data, so there should be data sent and received, thats not the problem.

Comment: Pff, let's step back, because I think we're not on the same page: what is this mysterious "no data received" error? Is it (1) the browser complaining the script does not send any output or (2) some error you are manually setting in your testing of memcache?

Comment: No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: this is the response from chrome, although theres multiple var dump or echos in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making sure memcache worked perfectly with python, I knew something was wrong with my memcache.so file. I read through forums and found out I had to put several arguments when running /.configure for the extension. I rebuilt it properly, and now it works fine.